# Mutex is already created before creating first instance

Tags: c#, mutex

I have a program that check if it is already running by doing this during startup:

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Programname", out createdNew);
if (!createdNew)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The program is already running.");
    return;
}
```

This has worked for years. Now some customers are saying they get this after a fresh restart of windows on first run of the program.

Did Microsoft change something? Is there a flaw in this system?

EDIT:
Turns out this was correct, user started it twice. Problem was it used longer than usual during startup, and not showing a window. So user started it again... Should i delete question?

Comment: use [WinObj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj). and check which process is having that mutex.

Comment: Is `Programname` a simple, straightforward word or words that some other program might also have selected? I'd almost always recommend using a GUID or other *highly unlikely to be duplicated by accident* string.

Comment: I find it in WinObj if i run it as Administrator and run my own program. But i find no reference there to what program holds it, even if i know in this instance. Any tips? The name is not Programname, but it is the name of out company and the program name and there should be no crash in naming.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060620-13/?p=30813

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine

1. Users told windows to restart, but it did not due to running programs. I have noticed recent versions of windows eventually going back to the login screen if some application does not shutdown.
2. Users double clicking on things, launching multiple copies.

You might want to change the behavior to not show a messagebox, but rather send a message/signal to the application holding the lock telling it "please take focus or restore the window and respond when done".

If a response is received within some time, you can just shutdown the current instance. If a response is not received you might ask the user something like "Another application is running but does not seem responsive, do you want to restart?"

This would be a bit more to code, but should result in a better user experience.

Comment: It was actually working correctly, just bad info from windows/user as you hint to in 1. IT used longer than usual starting up beofe a window was shown, so user started it twice.